# Using one data extension for journeys and contact updates via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, performance

Would it be a good practice (looking at performance) to setup one Data Extension that stores all contacts/Subscribers (including 20 attributes) and to let this Data Extension be updated via REST API calls from an external platform once a contact attribute changes in the CRM system?

And in addition, using this Data Extension as entry event in journey builder to send newsletters to.

Data Extension will contain more than 20 million records(subscribers).
Number of API calls is hard to estimate, but contact records in CRM are updated / added continuously.

Note: I'm aware of the API limitations of SFMC (We can throttle the calls), but looking for any performance considerations regarding using the same DE to receive these calls, and to be used in Journey Builder for email sends.

Thanks!

Comment: I would say, that is a pretty deep and wide table so there will be impacts on performance, especially related to filtering, SQL and lookups to it, but it likely can be manageable. But it is not a scalable process. As your subscriber base increases or you add more fields, the performance will degrade exponentially.

Comment: @Gortonington We are now thinking of using this DE just to receive the API calls, but to send to mails from dedicated DE's for each newsletter (Populated via SQL).
This DE will just contain the Contacts + optin info and standard demographics. We don't expect to add (a lot more) columns since we have separate DE's for Marketing/profile data.
Looking at the type of API call to use to sent the upserts to this DE, we are thinking of using the REST async API call. Would that make sense vs Sync / Soap?